# Skype messages in PHP

Tags: php, skype

Is there any way to send message to skype user without using COM?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only an API for ActiveX (COM).

Comment: You can use the Skype API with PHP. Just open up Wireshark and decode the API by hand. ActiveX is old and should never be used.

Comment: @Time Machine: Do you have a manual for this? Sounds very interesting!

Comment: @Time Machine: It will be great if you can tell about it more :)

Comment: Well, if you are into punishment and packet-sniffing, and decoding of APIs you can do this with any software, ranging from Skype to MSN, from a web browser to a BitTorrent application. The most pain will be felt when SSL is used. I don't know a manual for this and I've never done this before, but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score -1):

[This service](http://www.connectotel.com/sms/skype.html) allows you to send messages to Skype users via SMS. You can send SMS from your app using [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) or [ZeepMobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/). Unfortunately, this requires you to either pay for each message or have an ad in it.